# Google Bar Chart: Duplicate number of rows drawn

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm showing the results of a face emotion detection program as a google bar chart. The problem is that for every result set that is returned, the chart draws double the number of rows.

[BarGraphWithDuplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJpA9.png)

```js
<script>
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
</script>
 <button onclick="stopTextColor();">Stop</button> 
 <img id="bg" width=1200px height=900px src="{{ url_for('calc') }}">
 <div id="chart"></div>
 </body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var intervalID = setInterval(update_values,1000);
  function update_values() {
  
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/result',
               
      function(data) {
        $('#result').text(data.result);
        console.log(data);  
  drawMultSeries(); 

function drawMultSeries() {

var tdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data.result, true);
  
tdata.addRows(data.result);


   var options = {

       height: 500,
                            width:  500,
                            chartArea:{left:100,top:100,right:100,bottom:100},
                            hAxis: { ticks: [25,50,75,100] },       
                            isStacked: false,
                            bar: {groupWidth: '10'},
                            vAxis:{ textStyle:{color: '#000000',fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '0',marginRight: '0'}},
                            colors: ['green','#ffff99','#ffbf0c','red'],
                         };
    
    
     var chart1 = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                    chart1.draw(tdata, options);
     
    } 
      });
      
    };
    function stopTextColor() {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
    
</script>
```

When I inspect the array that is returned, there are only 7, but the graph as you can see shows 14. The next 7 rows are a replica of the first 7. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this statement...

```
tdata.addRows(data.result);
```

the rows are already being added here...

```
var tdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data.result, true);
```